# In back propagation why is this necessary, o (1 - o)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

To calculate the error in back propagation you would use, (target out - act. out) * act.out * (1 - act.out)

So what does, act.out * (1 - act.out) solve?

Wouldn't, [target out - act. out] be the amount the output is incorrect by?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It solves the derivative of the neuron output with respect to the current activation level. If you are using [logistic sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) for the activation function, then if `f(x)` is the sigmoid output for activation `x`, the derivative `df/dx` is equal to `f(x)(1 - f(x))`.

In the backpropagation equation, to determine by how much you should change a weight, you need an estimate of how sensitive the output is to a change in activation. That is what this term provides.